# How to preserve variable value between application starts in ASP.Net Core MVC?

Tags: asp.net-core, variables, asp.net-core-mvc, persistence, application-data

I have an ASP.NET Core MVC application that might be restarted from time to time (maintenance); how can make some variable values persistent from an execution to the next?

PS: That's the code that needs to write value as persistent. For example "LastMaintenanceRestartTime = 03/04-2020", the maintenance restart occurs once a day so the code needs to remember the last time it was restarted.

In UWP, I could do the following code but I can't seem to find an equivalent for ASP.NET Core:

```
Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings.Values[key] = value;
```

The best I could find is the following code but the values are only persistent within the same execution:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData(key, value);
```

Some talk about "Application.Settings" but I can't seem to be able to reach this namespace...

I've also seen some people talking about "AppSettings" files that can be modified during execution but it seems rather complex to keep a simple value persistent...

Do you have any recommendation, solution or ideas for me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution:

```
static void ReadSetting(string key)  
        {  
            try  
            {  
                var appSettings = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings;  
                string result = appSettings[key] ?? "Not Found";  
                Console.WriteLine(result);  
            }  
            catch (ConfigurationErrorsException)  
            {  
                Console.WriteLine("Error reading app settings");  
            }  
        }  

        static void AddUpdateAppSettings(string key, string value)  
        {  
            try  
            {  
                var configFile = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);  
                var settings = configFile.AppSettings.Settings;  
                if (settings[key] == null)  
                {  
                    settings.Add(key, value);  
                }  
                else  
                {  
                    settings[key].Value = value;  
                }  
                configFile.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);  
                ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection(configFile.AppSettings.SectionInformation.Name);  
            }  
            catch (ConfigurationErrorsException)  
            {  
                Console.WriteLine("Error writing app settings");  
            }  
        }
```

Link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.configuration.configurationmanager.appsettings?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0#System_Configuration_ConfigurationManager_AppSettings

Answer (score -1):

Create a model to save data and last execution time

```
public class ApplicationData {
      public DateTime LastExecutionTime {get;set;}
      public string Data {get;set;}
      public bool isRunningFirstTime {get;set}
   }
```

1.On first application run, model should be updated to current values and `isRunningFirstTime` should be set to false.
2. On second run, read or update values based on date and application running count

Comment: How about the writing part? I need the code to write the variable as persistent for the next execution...

Comment: How would you persist data to any given json file? Use the same approach.

Comment: @rashidali Sorry but I'm missing how to save the model... That's what I'm looking for...

Comment: @ChrisCavell So the best way is to create a physical file to hold properties?

Comment: Not necessarily, you could persist to database just as well. Basically take what @rashidali has given you and persist in a way that works best for your scenario.

Comment: @ChrisCavell I'm searching for the best way to do it, and especially how to do it (the saving part)...

Comment: Not necessarily the best way but a way I do things is I have an [AppSettings](https://github.com/cdcavell/cdcavell.name/blob/master/Source/Web/cdcavell/Models/AppSettings/AppSettings.cs) model class where I store application configuration settings. Mostly bound to appsettings.json but some fields from other sources. One such is `LastModifiedDate`. Not what you are asking (many examples of persisting data out there) but shows how I am reading file attribute to set value. You could just as easily read from file or database.

Answer (score -1):

Expanding on @rashidali answer (and not saying best, but):

```
public class ApplicationData 
{
      private DateTime _lastExecutionTime;
      public DateTime LastExecutionTime 
      {
            get
            {
                  _lastExecutionTime = (read from file/database);
                  return _lastExecutionTime;
            }
            set
            {
                  _lastExecutionTime = value;
                  (write _lastExecutionTime to file/database);
            }
      }
      public string Data {get;set;}
      public bool isRunningFirstTime {get;set}
}
```